# Ubuntu file sharing permission issues

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, mac

I'm having issues trying to set up file sharing on my Ubuntu PC. Recently my wife has upgraded her PC to an iMac, and I have taken possession of the PC. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on the PC. Now my wife is a graphic designer. I still have a lot of her files on the now Ubuntu PC, and I wanted to share the folder so she could access her files easily from her iMac.

I followed a few tutorials, but they all seem to get me to the same issue. When I try to access the folder from  her iMac or my Ubuntu laptop, it won't let me in (permissions denied??). I can see the folder on the network from both, but just can't access it. From my Ubuntu laptop, I get the revolving door Authentication Required. I type the password and try to connect, but it just pops back with the same box.

[image: Authentication Required Prompt]

On my wife's iMac at first it found the folder, but I was denied access to it (I wish I had screenshots of the prompt), but now after the first attempt it just tells me 'Connection Failed' whenever I try to click on the Ubuntu PC.

*It looks like you are attemping to access a samba share. What we don't know is how you created it. Please add to your original question the output of the following commands on the server: testparm -s and net usershare info --long –
Morbius1*

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

# Global parameters
[global]
    security = USER
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
```

and

```
[LinuxHD]
path=/media/jitz/DATA/User
comment=all the old stuff
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=n

[folder on linux]
path=/home/jitz/files to share
comment=test folder
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=y
```

The 'LinuxHD' folder is the one i' looking to share, the 'folder on linux' was a test.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: How are you "sharing" the files? Could you set up an account for `shinobi` and not use Anonymous Access?

Comment: Hi @waltinator, My apologies, 
The RP I followed initially can be found here; https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/build-linux-web-server-computer-part-1/ using Ubuntu instead of Lubuntu(which might have been my first issue).
In step 3 of the RP, it mentions to "Search for and install the following package names, each of which will include various prerequisites: apache2, php5, php5-mysql, and mysql-server" none of which I could find, so I chose to do the alternate of 'sudo apt install lamp-server^ -y'. and from there i can't remember now because I have been to muc other stuff today. Thank you

Comment: Thank you @karel for the edit. Grammar and spelling is something I struggle with.

Comment: @waltinator there is an account for shinobi, but it resorts back to that screenshot after I try to log in. Ultimately, the goal was, for my wife to be able to access her previous files on the hard drive from her iMac. If i am able to set the Ubuntu PC up so i can access files remotely from my Ubuntu laptop, then that is a bonus.

Comment: It looks like you are attemping to access a samba share. What we don't know is how you created it. Please add to your original question the output of the following commands on the server: `testparm -s` and `net usershare info --long`

Comment: Thank you @Morbius1 , I have added the outputs in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend for you to use defined IP address over your network (like 192.168.0.3 and 192.168.4 ...) and NOT DHCP

I recommend for you also to try to use nitroshare program (cross platform Linux, windows, mac)

https://nitroshare.net/

(android not available)

Answer (score 0):

```
[LinuxHD]
path=/media/jitz/DATA/User
comment=all the old stuff
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=n
```

Assuming "jitz" is a linux user name that is the only user that will be able to access the /DATA/User folder.

If you want to access that share as that user on the client machine you need to add that user to the samba password database:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a jitz
```

If you want others to access that share you need to add a local Ubuntu user to the server then add them to smbpasswd.

You will also need to edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and add under the `workgroup = WORKGROUP` line this one:

```
force user = jitz
```

**EDIT: Then restart smbd:**

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Note: I hope that your output of the testparm command is not complete. If it is you have disabled anonymous access ( guest access ) to your machine.

Comment: I have added the users. But I am unable to edit /etc/samba/smb.conf as it tells me i am not the administrator of the file.
Also that was the complete output of testparm. If the access had been turned of i have either done it accidentally or it was already off

Comment: I don't know how far you are going to get with such an incomplete smb.conf but to edit it as root run the following command in a terminal: `gedit admin:///etc/samba/smb.conf`